# Open source C program with little requirements and at least 2MB binary size

Tags: c, binary, size, requirements

I'm developing a operating system and I need a test program (function of any kind) to test certain internal features.
I cannot find any appropriate program to do this job. Probably one of you knows one.
The program should be open source, written in C with very little user library usage (only file IO, pthreads, stdio, stdlib preferred) and must have a binary size of at least 2MB.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Hello World with a 2MB NOP slide?

Comment: If you are writing an operating system, then writing such a user-mode application should be absolutely trivial for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* "Big Hello". */
/* Hereby placed in the public domain. */
#include <stdio.h>

char mem[1<<21] = { 1 };

int main(void)
{
    printf( "Hello, world!\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Seriously though, I doubt a particular file size of the executable is really what you want.  What is it you really want from a program that a plain old "Hello world" isn't complicated enough to exercise?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different flavors of shells around that are open source. You should be able to chose one that uses the right functionalities from the OS to provide a good test.

The shells that are accessible in the busybox package are probably a good starting point.